# Not getting any result data in Postman while executing PHP script

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, android-webservice

I have hosted my php file on AWS EC2 instance(runs Ubuntu). My other php files are getting perfectly executed and giving me desired output while the following code produces an error.

> ERROR : 500 Internal Server Error and shows hat unexpected end of File

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   include 'init.php';
    showData();
}

function showData()
{
    global $connect;
    $mandir_Cat_Id = $_POST["mandir_Cat_Id"];

    $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT mandir_id,mandir_Name from tblmandirMain WHERE mandir_Category_FK=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $mandir_Cat_Id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();

    //$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    if ($result->num_rows === 0) {
        $array["message"] = "Data not found";
        $array["status"] = "404";
    } else {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $array["results"][] = $row;
        }
        $array["message"] = "Data found";
        $array["status"] = "200";

    }

    mysqli_close($connect);
    header('Content-Type:Application/json');
    echo json_encode($array);
}
?>
```

The code runs perfectly and gives me the following JSON output :

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "mandir_id": 1,
        "mandir_Name": "Somnath Jyotirlinga"
    },
    {
        "mandir_id": 2,
        "mandir_Name": "Mallikarjuna Jyotirlinga"
    },
    {
        "mandir_id": 3,
        "mandir_Name": "Mahakaleshwar Jyotirlinga"
    },
    {
        "mandir_id": 4,
        "mandir_Name": "Omkareshwar Jyotirlinga"
    },
    {
        "mandir_id": 5,
        "mandir_Name": "Vaidyanath Jyotirlinga"
    },
    {
        "mandir_id": 6,
        "mandir_Name": "Kedarnath Temple"
    },
    {
        "mandir_id": 7,
        "mandir_Name": "Bhimashankar Jyotirling"
    },
    {
        "mandir_id": 8,
        "mandir_Name": "Trimbakeshwar Shiva Temple"
    },
    {
        "mandir_id": 9,
        "mandir_Name": "Kashi Vishwanath Temple"
    },
    {
        "mandir_id": 10,
        "mandir_Name": "Nageshwar Jyotirlinga"
    },
    {
        "mandir_id": 11,
        "mandir_Name": "Ramanathaswamy Temple"
    },
    {
        "mandir_id": 12,
        "mandir_Name": "Ghrishneshwar Jyotirlinga Temple"
    }
],
"message": "Data found",
"status": "200"
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is this script that is generating the error. If it creates output it seems unlikely

Comment: Yes..When i run it on server it gives error..

Comment: But it also gives you a full result?

Comment: No it doesnt...The json result which I have pasted in the question is the result which i get when i run the php script in my local machine..On server i dont get this result.

Comment: Then what was the comment _The code runs perfectly and gives me the following JSON output_ all about?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write there that it runs perfectly on my local machine..My bad.

Comment: Ret adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. It did showed me the error. It was a silly error by the way. But thanks...